# Web API not returning response after LinqToTwitter query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-twitter

I have an issue where after making a query to twitter via the LinqToTwitter library from within a web api controller, my code stops executing and the web api action fails to return a response.  I suspect that there is possibly some sort of conflict between web api and linqToTwitter, but I am totally clueless here.  Here is the code:

```
// This class is my wrapper for linqToTwitter
public class Twitter
{

// FIELDS
    private readonly MvcAuthorizer _auth;

    // PROPERTIES
    public TwitterContext Twit
    {
        get
        {
            return new TwitterContext(_auth);
        }
    }
public Twitter()
    {
        // all keys
        var cKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
            "twitConsumerKey"];
        var cSecKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
            "twitConsumerSecret"];
        var oToken = AuthTool.getUserTwitterTokens().token;
        var oTokenSecc = AuthTool.getUserTwitterTokens()
            .tokenSecret;

        ICredentialStore cred = new InMemoryCredentialStore();
        cred.ConsumerKey = cKey; 
        cred.ConsumerSecret = cSecKey;
        cred.OAuthToken = oToken;
        cred.OAuthTokenSecret = oTokenSecc;

        // get auth
        _auth = new MvcAuthorizer()
                {
                    CredentialStore = cred
                };
    }

// This is the specific method called from within the web api action
public string RetrieveTwitterId(string twitName)
{
    // this statement executes a successful linqToTwitter query as verified with fiddler 
    // but doesn't return anything to the user variable. The rest of the code does not execute.
    var user = Twit.User.SingleOrDefault
        (x => x.Type == UserType.Show &&
               x.ScreenName == twitName);

    if(user != null)
    {
       return user.UserID.ToString("F0");
    }
    return null;
 }
 }
```

This is the web api action being called:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateNewInterview(Model.NewInterview interview)
    {
        // find twitter Id
        var twitterId = new Twitter().RetrieveTwitterId(interview.SubjectTwitterName);// nothing is returned here and nothing executes below


        // assign model
        var model = new NewInterview
            (interview.Title, twitterId, DateTime.Now, interview.PublicQuestions,   interview.Category);

        // create the new interview
        Admin.createInterview(model);

        // create response
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show me how you made your `AuthTool` Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had these using statements in my twitter wrapper file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;// <-- Had to remove this one!!!
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LinqToTwitter;
using LinqToTwitter.Security;
using TwitterTools;
```

Caused an ambiguous error.  Still don't fully understand why this was happening in my original code though.